# How to draw an arrow between two layout's centers?

Tags: android

I have a custom ChessBoard view component. It contains 64 chess cells. Each cell is a FrameLayout.

I want to show an arrow between the cells centers, after a player move a chess piece from one cell to another. Have you any ideas, how to do that?

Comment: I think you can do it with a canvas over all your ChessBoard.

Comment: I afraid If I will draw an arrow on ChessBoard canvas. The arrow will be hidden behind cells

Comment: override `ChessBoard#draw` or `ChessBoard#dispatchDraw` method and do your drawing there

Comment: Ok. I see. The draw() method paints a view with all children. If I draw an arrow after super method, my arrow will be dispayed above the view. 

But I need some trick, because of the chess piece should hide the arrow's end. This mean I should something like draw a chess board witout chess pieces, draw an arrow, draw chess pieces